# Finding exe/dll path that works in single exe and running through "dotnet <program.dll>"

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

Is there a way of getting the location of the current exe or dll that works regardless of if we're running from a standalone exe or invoked from dotnet?

`Environment.ProcessPath` works for a single file exe, but if the program is invoked with "dotnet <program.dll>" then it returns the folder where the dotnet runtime is installed.

`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` works for being invoked from dotnet, but doesn't work for a single file exe.

Is there a method that works for both? Can I detect I'm in one situation or the other and invoke the correct method based on that?

Comment: "getting the location": isn't that what `AppContext.BaseDirectory` returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docs for single-file deployment and executable mention that [some `Assembly` APIs will not work in this mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli#api-incompatibility), including `Location`, which will return an empty string:

| API | Note |
| --- | --- |
| `Assembly.CodeBase` | Throws `System.PlatformNotSupportedException`. |
| `Assembly.EscapedCodeBase` | Throws `System.PlatformNotSupportedException`. |
| `Assembly.GetFile` | Throws `System.IO.IOException`. |
| `Assembly.GetFiles` | Throws `System.IO.IOException`. |
| `Assembly.Location` | Returns an empty string. |
| `AssemblyName.CodeBase` | Returns `null`. |
| `AssemblyName.EscapedCodeBase` | Returns `null`. |
| `Module.FullyQualifiedName` | Returns a string with the value of `<Unknown>` or throws an exception. |
| `Marshal.GetHINSTANCE` | Returns -1. |
| `Module.Name` | Returns a string with the value of `<Unknown>`. |

There are some workarounds mentioned:

- To access files next to the executable, use `System.AppContext.BaseDirectory`
- To find the file name of the executable, use the first element of `System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`, or starting with .NET 6, use the file name from `System.Environment.ProcessPath`.
- To avoid shipping loose files entirely, consider using embedded resources.

So base on this info you can take `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` and if it is empty string - use `Environment.ProcessPath` or just use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]`.

From [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs` remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?view=net-7.0):

> The first element in the array contains the file name of the executing program. If the file name is not available, the first element is equal to String.Empty. The remaining elements contain any additional tokens entered on the command line.
>
> In .NET 5 and later versions, for single-file publishing, the first element is the name of the host executable.